# Not able to post http request using TextEditingController variable in JSON body

Tags: flutter, http, texteditingcontroller

I am not able to post http request using `TextEditingController` in JSON body, but same code is working if I directly pass the string to JSON body

```
    class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
      late String name1;
      late String email1;
      late String phone1;
      late String pass1;
      late String pass2;
      TextEditingController name = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController email = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController phone = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController password = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController confirmpassword = new TextEditingController();
    
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                key: _formkey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 70,
                      child: Image.network(
                          "https://protocoderspoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/PROTO-CODERS-POINT-LOGO-water-mark-.png"),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: name,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: buildInputDecoration(Icons.person, "Full Name"),
                        validator: (String? value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Please enter name";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (String? name) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: email,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: buildInputDecoration(Icons.email, "Email"),
                        validator: (String? value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Please enter  email";
                          }
                          if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
                              .hasMatch(value)) {
                            return "Please enter valid email";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (String? email) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: phone,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: buildInputDecoration(Icons.phone, "Phone No"),
                        validator: (String? value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Please enter  phone";
                          }
                          if (value.length < 9) {
                            return "Please enter valid phone";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (String? phone) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: password,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: buildInputDecoration(Icons.lock, "Password"),
                        validator: (String? value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Please enter password";
                          }
    
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: confirmpassword,
                        obscureText: true,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration:
                            buildInputDecoration(Icons.lock, "Confirm Password"),
                        validator: (String? value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Please enter re-password";
                          }
                          if (password.text != confirmpassword.text) {
                            return "Password Do not match";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 50,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            RegistrationUser();
                            print("Successful");
                          } else {
                            print("Unsuccessfull");
                          }
                        },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("Submit"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future RegistrationUser() async {
        var APIURL =
            "https://heythere14168465465.000webhostapp.com/registration.php";
        name1 = name.text;
        email1 = email.text;
        phone1 = phone.text;
        pass1 = password.text;
        pass2 = 'd55';
        print(name1);
        print(email1);
        print(phone1);
        print(pass1);
    
        http.Response reponse = await http.post(Uri.parse(APIURL), body: {
        
          "name": name1,   
          "email": email1,
          "phone": phone1,
          "password": pass1
        });
        //getting response from php code, here
        var data = jsonDecode(reponse.body);
        print("DATA: ${data}");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcom to SO, is your print statements show the data on console ? I mean these lines print(name1);
        print(email1);
        print(phone1);
        print(pass1); ?

Comment: thanks for responding, yes it shows in the console

Comment: but when i pass the same variable to json body it is not passed to my API but if I provide string value directly to json body it is passing the value. Also if I declare a variable and initialize it with string andpassing the variable works fine but when I assign same variable with text control variable results same problem

Comment: please help me im stuck since a week in this problem